# boost thread with c++ 11lambda

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost

How can I use boost thread with C++11 lambda?

The following code doesn't work:

```
int sum;
m_workerThread=new boost::thread([]()
        {
               for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
               {
                    sum=sum+i;
                }
        }
        );
```

I am getting compile error.

```
   Error    4   error C3493: 'sum' cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture mode has been specified
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the error, just need to capture `sum`. As-is, the lambda doesn't know what `sum` is:

```
m_workerThread = new boost::thread([&sum]()
//                                  ^^^^
    {
           for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
           {
                sum=sum+i;
           }
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks. What is the meaning of capture and I can see from other answers that [=],.. is also available, what if I have a class and have several variables?

Comment: @mans `[=]` means implicitly capture all variables by-value, which is incorrect here, because you need to capture by-reference. For that, `[&]` means implicitly capture all variables by-reference. But always good to be specific.

Comment: Thanks. Am I right to believe that [&] means that sum outside of lambda is updates, [=] means that the value of sum is captured at start but not updated (like passing sum into a function). do we have any other option?

Comment: @mans You'll find that `[=]` wouldn't compile in this situation anyway (thankfully for you!), since `operator()` on lambdas is `const` by default. But if you explicitly made the lambda `mutable`, then yeah, it would be captured at the start but not updated. There's only the two options in C++11 (value and reference), but C++14 allows generalized lambda capture. Just google that, far too long to explain in a comment and there are whole answers devoted to it.

Comment: @mans: Remark that for lambda's that are not used locally (threads, but also lambda's returned by the function), capturing local variables by reference can be dangerous because threads can still live when the function ends.  It's not a problem when the thread is joined inside the function.